# Codeigniter 3 SMTP with Office 365

Tags: php, email, smtp, office365, codeigniter-3

I am having difficulties sending email via SMTP using **CI3** and **Office 365**.

My website is hosted with BT.

I found [this sample](https://gist.github.com/csshuelva/56de1c46d75436f3e267e64c261429aa) code which I am using, it's the minimum test code for successful email sending over SMTP with Office 365.

In my **contact** controller I have the following code;

```
class Contact extends CI_Controller {

    public function test(){
        $config = [        
            'protocol' => 'mail',
            'smtp_host' => 'smtp.office365.com',
            'smtp_user' => 'MY_EMAIL',
            'smtp_pass' => 'MY_PASSWORD',
            'smtp_crypto' => 'tls',    
            'newline' => "\r\n", 
            'smtp_port' => 587,
            'mailtype' => 'html'    
        ];

        $this->load->library('email', $config);        
        $this->email->from('MY_FROM_EMAIL');        
        $this->email->to('MY_TO_EMAIL');        
        $this->email->subject('Test');
        $this->email->message('SMTP sending test');
        $sent = $this->email->send();

        if ($sent) {
            echo 'OK';
        } else {
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }
    }
}
```

When I visit my URL `example.com/contact/test` I see the following error;

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to smtp.office365.com:587
>   (Connection timed out)
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1990
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: .../controllers/Contact.php Line: 118 Function: send
>
> File: ../index.php Line: 341 Function: require_once

Then below that;

> The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out
>   Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be
>   configured to send mail using this method.
>
> User-Agent: CodeIgniter
>   Date: Tue, 14 Nov 2017 15:08:27 +0000
>   etc ...
>   etc ...
>   etc ...

I know the login details are correct for the email account as I am able to login and send/receive emails using various email clients.

Any ideas why this is happening, and how I can fix it? Are there any other tests I can carry put in order to help troubleshoot the issue.

I've been stuck at this for days. I don't want to use gmail or any other email provider.

Comment: Did you try to enable smtp connection in your account configuration ?

Comment: @YouneL I'm not sure where to do this, I have a regular 365 mail account (not admin). Also, is this necessary? I think it should work as standard without any configuration changes at the 365 end?

Comment: I was thinking maybe it's like gmail, but you can try to use ssl encription with port 465